# Sending json data to the database using postman.(status 500)

Tags: node.js, json, express, routes

I am trying to send json data using postman but there is internal server error which I don't understand the where it comes from. Connection and schemas are well established.
**CODE**

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const alert = require("alert");
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");
const registerUsers = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

  if (!email || !name || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please Enter All fields");
  }
  const userExists = await User.findOne({
    email,
  });
  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already exists");
  }
  const user = await User.create({ name, email, password, pic });
  if (user) {
    res.status(400).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      pic: user.pic,
      token: generateToken(user_id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Failed to create the account, try again after some time.");
  }
});
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {});
module.exports = { registerUsers };
```

**userRoutes.js file**

```
const { registerUsers } = require("../controllers/userControllers");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", registerUsers);
// router.route("/login").post(authUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js file.**

```
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
```

I'm expecting this data to be sent to the database with a post request to "/" route

```
{
    "name": "joseph ngatia",
    "email": "jngatia@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345"
}
```

, but i receive this error;

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Document.invalidate (C:\Users\User\MERN App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:3147:32)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\User\MERN App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2940:17<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\User\MERN App\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1350:9<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ooh yeah, I found it. I used `res.status(400)` on a probably successfull request here;

```js
const user = await User.create({ name, email, password, pic });
if (user) {
  res.status(400).json({
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    pic: user.pic,
    token: generateToken(user_id),
  });
}
```